# Table not rendering properly inside <div> tag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I want to load some data in a table when it is available, else show 'Loading'. My `render()` function is currently as shown below:

```
return (
    <div>
        { this.state.loaded ? <tbody>{tuples}</tbody> : 'Loading ...' }
    </div>
);
```

My problem is, without the `<div>` tags, I get a build error from Gulp, but with them, my table columns are not staying aligned with the data.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
return (this.state.loaded ? <tbody>{tuples}</tbody> : <span>Loading ...</span>);
```

---

The error you were getting was probably something like:

> **Uncaught Error:** Invariant Violation: App.render(): *A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.*

Basically, React wants your `render()` function to return a valid `ReactComponent`. Without your wrapping `<div>` you would've returned a string when `this.state.loaded` is `false`, but strings are not the same as `ReactComponent`, hence the error.

In the solution provided above, we are returning the `<tbody>` element if the `state.loaded` is `true` (as you did as well). However, if it's `false` we return the *"Loading ..."* string wrapped inside of a `<span>`, which is a valid `ReactComponent`.

Obviously, you could choose any other element other than `<span>` if you'd prefer that, but I do suggest using it in most cases since, by default, it doesn't bring any visual changes - which is convenient is scenarios such as this one.

Comment: That was indeed the error I was getting. I checked now. Thank you for this information..:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following:

```
return (

    <tbody>
            { this.state.loaded ? {tuples} : 'Loading ...' }
    </tbody>
    );
```

This will avoid the div element

Comment: This will also put `Loading...` inside the `<tbody>`. Not ideal.

Comment: This should work, but I get a minified exception in the console, and the table does not show at all.